# How can I fix Hebrew encoding so the Hebrew won't appear in Cyrillic letters in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I use Windows 8 on an HP Envy tablet. I've installed Hebrew as an additional language and it works with most programs, but with a few of them the Hebrew appears as Cyrillic letters or from left-to-right instead of right-to-left.

How can I fix the encoding to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the names of the programs which appear incorrectly? It may be specific program issue, not with windows.

Comment: In Region settings, Administrative, Language for non-Unicode programs - choose Hebrew (Israel)